# Linq sorting with multiple column names in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sorting, entity-framework-4

I want to sort multiple columns with Linq

I used [this link](http://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/24/orderby-string-in-linq-c-net-dynamic-sorting-of-anonymous-types/) for reference, which is used for sorting of single column by column name.

I am trying to use this method for sorting of multiple columns with column names.

Here is what i am doing so far

```
  public static IQueryable<T> OrderByMultipleFields<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, Dictionary<string, bool> fieldsToSort)
  {
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, fieldsToSort.First().Key);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
    string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
    string method=string.Empty;
    Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var mce = q.Expression;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var fieldName in fieldsToSort)
    {
      method = fieldName.Value ? methodAsc : methodDesc;
      prop = Expression.Property(param, fieldName.Key);
      exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
      types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
      if (count == 0) {
        mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
      } else {
        mce = Expression.Add(mce, Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp));
      }
      methodAsc = "ThenBy";
      methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
      count++;
    }
    return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
  }
```

I am getting following error -

> The binary operator Add is not defined for the types
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[SortDemo.Data.User]' and
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[SortDemo.Data.User]'.

what is the proper way to achieve this or is there any alternate approach or method for this.
thanks.

Comment: Well why are you *trying* to call `Expression.Add`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're trying to call `Add` in the first place. There are no addition operations in normal sorting code, so there wouldn't be in the expression tree form either.

I suspect you just want to replace this:

```
if (count == 0)
{
    mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
}
else {
    mce = Expression.Add(mce, Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp));
}
```

with:

```
mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
```

I'd also suggest moving the declarations of `method`, `types`, `exp` and `props` to inside the loop, as well... and removing `count`. That would leave you with:

```
string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
var mce = q.Expression;
foreach (var fieldName in fieldsToSort)
{
    var method = fieldName.Value ? methodAsc : methodDesc;
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, fieldName.Key);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    var types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
    methodAsc = "ThenBy";
    methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
}

return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
```

I haven't tried it but it's more likely to worth than what you had before.

Another thing to consider is not building up the *whole* expression tree like this, but instead calling the appropriate `Queryable` methods directly yourself via reflection. You'd then only need to build up a single property-access expression tree at any point.

Comment: I know its not required there, but I just posted my code as it is to show what i was trying.

Comment: @NikhilChavan: But *why* were you trying it? If you know that an unnecessary operation is causing you problems, why not just remove it? See my edit for sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will try your suggestion & check if working. Thanks.